# Interrupting the TCP handshake with PHP's fsockopen()?

Tags: php, tcp, sockets, fsockopen

Take for example:

`fsockopen(tcp:\\example.com, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5)`

My friend has just informed me that PHP will always wait for the TCP handshake to be completed before closing the socket. However, I find it difficult to believe that PHP can't interrupt the handshake.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not possible.